# Create a constant from a lookup in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a variable from a lookup in Ansible. I then want to use that variable as a constant throughout the rest of the role. Here are a couple of lines from `defaults/main.yml`.

```yaml
job_start_time: "{{ lookup('pipe','date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') }}"
new_virtual_machine_name: "{{ template_name }}-pkrclone-{{ job_start_time }}"
```

The result of running the role causes an error as the lookup happens again when the `new_virtual_machine_name` variable is used in `tasks/main.yml`. You can see the second increment in subsequent tasks.

```
TASK [update_vsphere_template : Write vsphere source file] changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "checksum": "c2ee7ed6fad0b26aea825233f3e714862de3ac28", "dest": "packer-DevOps-Windows2019-Base-DevOps-Windows2019-Base-pkrclone-20210819_**093122**/vsphere-source-DevOps-Windows2019-Base-DevOps-Windows2019-Base-pkrclone-20210819_**093122**.pkr.hcl", 148765781020136/source", "state": "file", "uid": 1000}

TASK [update_vsphere_template : Write the template update file] *fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "6fd97c1d2373b9c71ad6b5246529c46a38f55c48", "msg": "Destination directory packer-DevOps-Windows2019-Base-DevOps-Windows2019-Base-pkrclone-20210819_**093123** does not exist"}
```

Here is how I am referencing the new_virtual_machine_name variable in `tasks/main.yml`

```yaml
- name: Write vsphere source file
  template:
    src: ../templates/vsphere-source.j2
    dest: 'packer-{{template_name}}-{{ new_virtual_machine_name }}/vsphere-source-{{ template_name }}-{{ new_virtual_machine_name }}.pkr.hcl'

- name: Write the template update file
  template:
    src: ../templates/update-template.j2
    dest: 'packer-{{template_name}}-{{ new_virtual_machine_name }}/update-{{ template_name }}-{{ new_virtual_machine_name }}.pkr.hcl'
```

How can I keep Ansible from running the lookup every time I reference the variable that is created from the lookup at the start of the job? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"**How can I keep Ansible from running the lookup every time I reference the variable?**"*

A: Use [strftime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times), you'll get the current date each time you call the filter, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        job_start_time: "{{ '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'|strftime }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "pkrclone-{{ job_start_time }}"
    - wait_for:
        timeout: 3
    - debug:
        msg: "pkrclone-{{ job_start_time }}"
    - set_fact:
        job_start_time: "{{ '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'|strftime }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "pkrclone-{{ job_start_time }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: pkrclone-20210819_174748
  msg: pkrclone-20210819_174748
  msg: pkrclone-20210819_174753
```

Comment: If you put the `strftime` expression in a var instead of a fact, you still have the exact same problem as reported by OP. So what fixes the issue is using a fact, not using another way to get/format the date.

Comment: You're right. And you should get the credit. No question about that. The idea of using the lookup *pipe* plugin instead of *strftime* is wrong. I decided to put it into my answer instead of commenting on yours because it is neither [constructive criticism nor minor or transient information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work), I think.

Comment: `pipe` lookup plugin is really seldom a good idea ;) I just answered the original question without going further this time (I admit). I don't care that much about getting credit, just wanted to point out what was the real original problem. I'll edit my answer so it gets the best out of the two. Have a good night.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, variables are evaluated every time you call them. A way to work around this is to store a fact using `set_facts` which will be evaluated only at time it is set and stored as a static values for the host.

**Edit:** Note that, as pointed out in @vladimir's answer (and discussed in comments), using the `pipe` lookup to get such an info is not really a good practice when you have the `strftime` filter available in core Ansible. So I changed it in my below example.

To illustrate, the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    _job_start_time: "{{ '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'| strftime }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Force var into a fact that will be constant throughout play
      set_fact:
        job_start_time: "{{ _job_start_time }}"

    - name: Wait a bit making sure time goes on
      pause:
        seconds: 1

    - name: Show that fact is constant whereas inital var changes
      debug:
        msg: "var is: {{ _job_start_time }}, fact is: {{ job_start_time }}"

    - name: Wait a bit making sure time goes on
      pause:
        seconds: 1

    - name: Show that fact is constant whereas inital var changes
      debug:
        msg: "var is: {{ _job_start_time }}, fact is: {{ job_start_time }}"
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Force var into a fact that will be constant throughout play] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Wait a bit making sure time goes on] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Pausing for 1 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show that fact is constant whereas inital var changes] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "var is: 20210819_172528, fact is: 20210819_172527"
}

TASK [Wait a bit making sure time goes on] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Pausing for 1 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show that fact is constant whereas inital var changes] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "var is: 20210819_172529, fact is: 20210819_172527"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```